# Retrain TF object detection API to detect a specific car model -- How to prepare the training data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am new to object detection and trying to retrain object-detection API in TensorFlow to detect a specific car model in photos. When preparing my own training data to retrain the model, besides things like drawing bounding boxes, etc, my question is, should I also prepare negative examples in the training data (cars that are not the model I am interested in) to reach good performance?

I have read through some tutorials and they usually give example in detecting one type of object, and they prepared training data with the label only for that type. I was thinking, since the model first proposal some area of interest, then try to classify those areas, should I also prepare negative examples if I want to detect very specific stuff from photos.

I am retaining faster_rcnn based model. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need negative examples also for better performance. Seems like are you thinking about using transfer learning to train a pre-trained faster_rcnn model to add a new class for your custom car. You should start an equal number of positive and negative examples (images with labelled bounding boxes). You will need have examples of several negative classes (e.g. negative car type 1, negative car type 2, negative car type 3) in addition to your target car type.

You can look at examples of one positive class and several negative classes training data for transfer learning in the data folder of the my github repo at: [PSV Detector Github](https://github.com/siddiqaa/psvcounter)